# Microsoft routines for encrypting date for "this system only"

Tags: encryption, microsoft

Microsoft has many encryption APIs, but one that I used at my old company had specific properties.  The routines only decrypted the data if the decrypt was done on exactly the same system as it was encrypted on.  This allowed us to check the encrypted form of the password into source control because even given the data and the key, it wasn't possible to decrypt the data unless you had a login on the production server . . . which of course was closely held by only IT and our team.

I want to use that API for a new project and I've search Microsoft APIs, but I just cannot remember the names of the routines.

Has anyone used them recently enough to know their names?

Frank

Comment: What happens if I, or someone else, destroy(s) the production server? All encrypted data will be discarded as junk?

Comment: The answer is "this is a horrible idea and should never be used" imho.

Comment: you probably want to start here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection .

Comment: This is a bad idea, but presumably you could use something tied to tpm.

Comment: I found the concerns interesting but wanted to find the routine before commenting.  The name of the function is "CryptProtectData".  The concept seems brilliant to me so I am puzzled by the concerns.  In our case, the password was known and written down, and closely held by our team.  The goal was to keep the password out of source control check-in in the source.  We encode the password using CryptProtectData() on the production machine.  We could decode the password on the production machine only, so seeing the data blob in source control wasn't useful to anyone without access to the machine.

Comment: IT of course has production servers locked down pretty tight, so access was very limited.  If the production machine died, we'd just check in a newly updated blob.  Besides being "horrible" or "bad", I'd like to hear more about everyone's concerns.